# How to change the type of a column of an attribute table in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

So I want to change one of the columns in my table from string to real. How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: If the data is all real you do not need to change the field type, use to_real (field)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `Refactor Field` in the Processing Toolbox.

Go to Processing > Toolbox > QGIS geoalgorithms > Vector table tools > Refactor fields

[image: Processing Toolbox - Refactor fields]

This will open the Refactor fields window where you can select the layer that you want to make changes to.

[image]

From the `Type` drop down choose `Integer` or `Double` depending if you want a whole number or a decimal number, respectively, and choose the length.

[image]

You can choose to save the new altered layer to a location or if you leave it as default 'Save to temporary file' then 'Save as' the new 'Refactored' layer that is loaded into your project.

Comment: Ok, so I have done everything that you have said, but there remains a problem, after I converted my table into a new refactored layer, I am unable to use one of the refactored columns as an interval for graduated styling, how can I fix this?

Comment: This is a different question. Try searching for an answer on GIS Stack Exchange, or otherwise on the internet. If there is no answer you can find that helps then you can post a new question explaining what you are trying to do, and what you have tried. Does this help perhaps https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175633/manual-range-selection-for-graduated-style-vector-layer-in-qgis

Comment: I have fixed my problem now, there are two double options in my refactoring  interface, its the top one that works.