# Joined attribute not visible in categorized symbology

Tags: qgis, symbology, fields-attributes, attribute-joins, choropleth

I am having an issue selecting a joined layer in the 'value' dropdown under graduated symbology to create a choropleth map. I joined originally the data from a csv file, but after I encountered this issue I redid it using the Add Delimited Text Layer option. I thought the issue could be  occurring due to incorrect data type (string vs. numeric), so I used the `to_real()` function within the attribute table to change the data type of the particular attribute. I have referenced [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321720/qgis-joined-attributes-not-visible-in-categorized-symbology) on the same subject. However, even after completing the change of data type, the attribute still does not show up as an option under graduated symbology. There is one NULL entry, could this have an effect? I am not sure what is going wrong. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried deleting the feature with the NULL attributes to see if the attribute appears in your graduated list? An other point is, the function `to_int(NULL)` will give you NULL, you'd need something like `if("attribute" is NULL, 0, to_int("attribute")` to transform NULL values into a 0.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in the other post carefully, you don't need to change the datatype in the attribute table, you need to do it in the styling panel with expressions. You should not see `sheet_target` in the dropdown list, only `to_int(sheet_target)` (and only if it is the active field - if you change to something else it will disappear from the list). I have tried it with nulls in the data and it should not affect whether it appears in the list or not.

Comment: I have updated the answer in that post with some screenshots to make it clearer, hopefully that helps?