# Fields not showing in graduating symbols

Tags: symbology

I'm looking to apply a size based graduated style a point layer based on numerical values in the attribute table. Bigger value, bigger point. Basic procedure. However. In the symbology tab when I go to select the graduated value, the field II am looking for is absent... the majority of the fields are not selectable, despite me being able to view them in the attribute table. Below are 2 images. The first shows the symbology tab showing that I can't access the other fields. The second shows the layer properties and all the fields that are in the file. Can anyone tell me why I can't select these fields for graduated symbology?
[image: Symbology tab]

[image: Layer Properties]

Comment: I was able to fix this. The problem being all the fields were string. I used the refactor tool mentioned here. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247373/how-to-change-the-type-of-a-column-of-an-attribute-table-in-qgis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost every field in your table is a string-field and thus not available for graduate symbology (really, how would you graduate between different words, e.g.?). You need to convert your fields of interest to `integer` or `double` - either permanently, or "on the fly".

"on the fly" means you enter the expression you'd use for conversion directly into the field where you can choose which attribute to graduate by, e.g. `to_real("Three-spin")` - this would convert your field `Three-spin` to `double` and then create the symbology based on it.